# Encoding xml and saving to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, encoding

Have a Web application that let's you paste text and save it to database.

Text had € (euro currency) symbol and once it got to the database, it crashed while parsing the XML in SQL. Reason is invalid character.

I solved this by using C# to replace € with `&#8364;` in the Web API. Now XML contains `&#8364;` and it gets parsed into SQL. I look at the saved row in the database and it shows €. Great!

I go back to the Web application and pull up the text that was saved. I expect to see "€52.9mm" but instead, I see "52.9mm".

I hit F12, refresh and see that it does indeed retrieve "€52.9mm" which is what's stored in the database. But the UI shows "52.9mm".

For kicks, I change the value in the database to `&#8364; 52.9mm`. A refresh of the UI now shows "€52.9mm".

Would a practical solution be to save the text in the database as `&#8364; 52.9mm`?

If this works, how do I get it to save in this format which is how it is in the XML? But after it gets parsed by the SQL, it gets saved as €52.9mm.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: FYI the ` character is your friend if you want to literally quote something.

Comment: @spender, originally, I used double quotes and it didn't work. After your tip, I tried single quotes, but that doesn't work either. I copied your char and used it and it works. Is that the char at the top left keyboard (left of 1)?

Comment: Yes, on my EN-GB keyboard. Might be different elsewhere. Alternatively, highlight the text and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way would be to use `CDATA` wrapping your HTML inside your XML tag element. Then you dont need to worry about escaping or converting non-xml safe characters.

Now you haven't shown any detail on constructing this xml file but lets take a stadard XElement. To save the content as `CDATA` you simply write..

`xDocument.Add(new XElement("MyHtml", new XCData("<p>My HTML Content</p>"));`

**CDATA**

> CDATA sections may occur anywhere character data may occur; they are
>   used to escape blocks of text containing characters which would
>   otherwise be recognized as markup. CDATA sections begin with the
>   string  `<![CDATA[` and end with the string `]]>`

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect